# Express (probably) adds http://localhost:3000 before all external links on the page

Tags: javascript, express, hyperlink, static

I have some issue with express in my simply javascript app. I want to make a repository for URLs. On my page I display all links with this code:

```
const allLinks = links
        .map((link) => {
            const { _id: linkID, name, area, address } = link;
            return `
                <h5>${name}</h5>
                <h5>${area}</h5>
                <div>${address}</div>
                    <!-- edit link -->
                    <a href="edit.html?id=${linkID}" class="">
                        edit
                    </a>
                    <!-- delete btn -->
                    <button type="button" class="delete-btn" data-id="${linkID}">
                        delete
                    </button>
                </div>`;
        })
        .join('');

    linksDOM.innerHTML = allLinks;
```

Then on my page I see for example link (address) like: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). I've tried to make a clikable link from it (a tag, on click button), but there's an issue with it. Probably express treats it like link inside app and adds before the link http://localhst:3000, so it goes like http://localhost:3000/www.google.com and of course doesn't work. Same is when I right click and copy link. I just want an external working link, without localhost:3000.

How I can to prevent app/express to do this. Does anyone can help me, please ?

Comment: Start the URL with a protocol. In this instance either `http://` or `https://`. This will tell express that you're trying to link to a third-party site.

Comment: If the link in your page does not have a domain, then the BROWSER will add the domain from the current page onto the URL automatically and you cannot prevent that.  This is not done by Express, but by the browser.  So, if you want to specify a particular and different domain, you MUST put it into the URL in the page when you generate and send the page back to the browser.